# phpChart in Laravel

Tags: charts, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I need a library to generate some charts in my page. I found the [phpChart](http://phpchart.net/), but I do not know how to install it.

My question is: How to install phpChart in Laravel via composer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately if there are no packages on packagist, you cannot install it via Composer.

But you can still install it on Laravel:

1) Download and unzip it somewhere in `app/`, you can create an `app/libraries/phpChart` and unzip it there.

2) Edit your composer.json and add your folder to it:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "app/libraries"
    ]
},
```

3) Run `composer dump-autoload` so Composer create a new map for your library classes.